# Why does my text go outside the divs with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am fiddling around with Bootstrap, and everything is going quite well.
But when I make a div to put text in, the text sticks outside the div, making the page as wide as the string. Isn't bootstrap responsible for taking care of this?

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="row top-buffer">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col cell">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg12 inner">
      <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col cell">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg12 inner">
      <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put the relevant code into your question (a minimal example), not just link to it.

Comment: Well A) Thanks for that (not) B) thanks for destroying the bit of reputation that I had by downvoting C) I explained why I didnt put it in there, so this comment is completely obselete and useless. I had already come up with that myself.

Comment: The link points to code which doesn't reflect the problem the question is referring to anymore (one of the problems with linking to code). Please put the relevant code into the question. I didn't downvote, btw.

Comment: To keep the question somehow useful, I added the relevant HTML-code from memory.

Comment: *Isn't bootstrap responsible for taking care of this?*  LOL.  Not sure why that's so funny, but it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser doesn't do automatic hyphenation. Put some whitespaces in your text and it should work as expected.

Comment: I feel so dumb, it sees it all as one word. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use `style="word-wrap:break-word";`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the browser to automatically break your text you should add the css `word-wrap: break-word;` property. To your surrounding tag (in this case the `<p>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom width to your div, then either add a scrollbar or hide the text (`text-overflow:ellipsis`).