# text going outside the div in bootsrap after adding white-space pre

Tags: html, css

I have a div which will display content from multiple lines of text field

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="description ng-binding">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
         Nam porttitor varius tortor..
      </span>           
</div>
```

The description div sometimes need to display multiple line of text. But it displayed content in one line ignoring the next(new) line. So I added the below css

```
.description {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

After adding this, it displayed in multiple lines. But now the issue is, if the line is large, then its going outside the parent div and its not contained inside the div.

I tried adding the below css as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240334), but it didn't work

```
.description {
    white-space: pre;
    max-width: 98%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try `word-break:break-all;` ?

Comment: Yeah @JuanCaicedo I tried it

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css from `white-space:pre` to `white-space:pre-wrap` and it worked

```
.description{
    white-space: pre;
}
```